# flink watermark merging strategy for parrallel tasks

Tags: apache-flink

I have task which consume data from kafka which have 5 partition, and then use window function to do some calculation.

My question is that :

If it occurs that there occurs lag in partition 1 consumption,for example 1 min late, other partition is normal.
Because of the watermark strategy and window size limit (1 min), and use monotonously watermark strategy, will partition 1 will always be regarded as late data.

Source Code Snippet:

```
//1.get kafka source datastream
DataStream<byte []> kafkaData = env.fromSource(kafkaSource, 
WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), 
"kafka-log").setParallelism(12).rebalance()；
//2.parse byte[] into object
DataStream<Tuple2<Long, HashMap<String,Object>>> ds = KafkaData.flatMap(ConverterFlatMapFunction).name(...).setParallelism(24);
//3.generate watermark
DataStream<Tuple2<Long, HashMap<String, Object>>> watermarkAndLog = ds.assignTimestampAndWatermakrs(WatermarkStrategy.<...>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(120)).withTimestampAssigner((tuple,1)->tuple.f0).setParallelism(24);
//4.Do some process and no window operation
DataStream<Tuple2<String, String[]>> midData = ...;
//5.window operation
DataStream<> result = midData.keyBy(tuple->tuple.f0)
.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(1)))
.reduce(someReduceFunction).name("window-process").setParallelism(6);
//6.and sink
result.addSink(.....);
```

Comment: Please provide more details of your workflow. E.g. are you doing a `keyBy()` before the window function?

Answer (score 0):

By default a Flink task will move its watermark forward according to the minimum of ALL its input tasks. In your case the lag one will be the bottleneck for the watermark. Data from partition 1 won't be regarded as late data. Downstream operator might often have to buffer data from other partitions because they're faster than partition 1, but the window can't be triggered because partition 1 has not catched up. Sometimes such bufferring might bring operator state size issue.

You can find more details from [Watermark alignment Beta](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/#watermark-alignment-_beta_) about how to keep them aligned. However you have 1 lag partitions but n - 1 fast ones, I guess you might not need to do alignment unless you have a problem with state size.